# 3d paint effect in Blender

Tags: color

I'm quite new to Blender so I appreciate any and all help. I would like to know if it is possible to create something similar to this pictures in Blender. Thanks

[image: picture 1][image: picture 2]

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to use a series of curves with a custom bevel. Create your paint patterns as a texture (with transparency enabled), and apply them to the curves.

It should take (except for the textures) just a few minutes.

Make your curve(s), adjust them using both handles and vertex weight and tilt, then in the curve tab apply bevel (half) (rounded) or whatever profile you want.

I did this with a very simple paint smear.
[image: Beveled Curve]

This is the node setup for the transparency

[image: PNG Transparency]

And this is the png I used. I had to adjust the z rotation to make the stripes the long way.

To get brush texture--not shown here--you can just run the image into a bump node for height and throw that into normal on the principaled BSDF shader.

[image: Paint Smear png]

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it was possible to do it in such a short time! Thank you so much for your help, this is the first time I’m going to use Blender, but I think that by following the steps you’ve described I’ll be able to do it :)

Comment: Good luck. It can be a little confusing at first, learning how to manipulate curves, but they're really easy (and fun) once you get to know them. This is a great intro to custom curve bevels: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJsxKWxAhMk

Comment: thank you again for your kindness!

Comment: Hi Modeler101,
I've already managed to learn a little more about curves and bevel. But the end result was very different from yours. I followed the same setup as you, but I couldn't get it to be transparent: https://imgur.com/a/MPhUcFg/

Could you give me one more help please? I really want to learn how to do it.

Comment: Hi Taylor, I can't tell what's going on from the images. You seem to have created some geometry in the bevel, so it looks like a solid. This could be a setting in a newer version--I'm running 2.91. I'm trying to figure out the best way to send you my model so you can see if it works for you.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DAd5GS3V" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DAd5GS3V/)

Comment: Hi Modeler101, I don't know what i did wrong, your model looks so much better! Thank you so much for sending me your model, this way i can understand and learn how to do it :)